# Always getting a empty object in unitTest JPA/Hibernate

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, junit, spring-data-jpa

I am currently trying if my functions work with my current database but I keep getting an empty object back. My Test is the following:

```
@Test
    public void findJobOfferByIdReturnsCorrectJobOffer() {
        User user = UserBuilder.anUser().build();

        JobOffer firstJobOffer = JobOfferBuilder.aJobOffer()
                .withId(108L)
                .withCompany(user)
                .build();

        JobOffer secondJoboffer = JobOfferBuilder.aJobOffer()
                .withAmountPerSession(55)
                .withCompany(user)
                .withId(208L)
                .withJobDescription("Software Tester in PHP")
                .build();

        userDao.saveUser(user);
        jobOfferDao.saveJobOffer(firstJobOffer);
        jobOfferDao.saveJobOffer(secondJoboffer);
        entityManager.clear();
        entityManager.flush();

        Optional<JobOffer> retrievedJobOffer = jobOfferDao.findJobOfferById(firstJobOffer.getId());
        assertTrue(retrievedJobOffer.isPresent());
        JobOffer jobOffer = retrievedJobOffer.get();

        assertEquals(jobOffer.getId(), firstJobOffer.getId());
        assertNotEquals(jobOffer.getId(), secondJoboffer.getId());
    }
```

The Test uses the following DAOImpl repository:

```
@Repository
public class JobOfferDaoImpl implements JobOfferDao {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(UserDaoImpl.class);

    @Override
    public Optional<JobOffer> findJobOfferById(Long id) {
        TypedQuery<JobOffer> jobOfferQuery = entityManager.createNamedQuery("findJobOfferById", JobOffer.class);
        jobOfferQuery.setParameter("jobOfferId", id);
        try {
            return Optional.of(jobOfferQuery.getSingleResult());
        } catch (NoResultException e) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }

    @Transactional
    public void saveJobOffer(JobOffer jobOffer) {
        if (findJobOfferById(jobOffer.getId()).isEmpty()) {
            entityManager.merge(jobOffer);
            LOGGER.info(String.format("Joboffer with id %d is inserted in the database", jobOffer.getId()));
        } else {
            throw new JobOfferNotFoundException();
        }
    }
}
```

And the Query to select the correct jobOffer for "findJobOfferById" is the following:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "findJobOfferById", query = "SELECT j from JobOffer j WHERE j.id = :jobOfferId"),
```

When trying to debug I get the following:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the Test you shouldn't give your own ID. Change it with:

```
.withId(null)
```

And in the DAO you have to Persist the jobOffer and actually add it. With merge you are modifying it.

```
entityManager.persist(jobOffer);
```